# Python read from list

Tags: python

I have a question about lists in python and how to print from them. Which of the following code snippets prints all 7 words found in the list "words"? I have compiled and tried it but I still don't know which of this snippets is correct.

```
1.
i = 0 
while i < 7: 
    print(words[i], end=" ")
i += 1

2.
i = 0 
while i < 7: 
    print(words[i], end=" ")
    i += 1
3.
i = 1 
while i < 7: 
    print(words[i], end=" ")
    i += 1

4.
i = 0 
sum = "" 
while i < 7: 
    sum += words[i] 
    i += 1 
print(sum)

5.
i = 0 
sum = "" 
while i <= 7: 
    sum += words[i] 
    i += 1 
print(sum)
```

Comment: What output do you get when you try?

Comment: FYI, `print " ".join(words)` would more pythonic.

Comment: Can I go for `print(*words, sep='\n')`? Seriously though - why don't you just run them and see? And what is correct - you're in the best position to determine that surely?

Comment: I hope this isn't from a course where they are teaching Python. It looks like a question that's been "ported" from some other language.

Comment: Is your question how to run them, or which is the correct answer? Hurry it's about to be closed.

Comment: #2 is correct. Why on earth can't you run these to figure it out, though?

Answer (score 2):

If your list looks something like this, `words = ["a","b","c"..]`,

All you have to do is iterate over them using the `for` statement,

```
for i in words:
    print i
```

That should print out the words:

```
a
b
c
....
```

Comment: This is wrong. I think you meant **print i**

Comment: @radicalbiscuit Thanks. I guess I am a bit tired.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be all that difficult to follow as a dry run (use pen and paper if you need to).
You'll need to remember that if `words` has 7 elements, they are words[0]...words[6]. ie the list index starts at 0

Obviously you haven't been able to run them. How did you try to run them? What went wrong?

If you still can't work it out, a good strategy is to fall back to the answer that has the most in common with the other answers...answer 2 :)

Comment: That's horribly unpythonic and isn't resuable.  What do you do when there are 6 results.. etc.  @enginefree got it right.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: None are correct. They are all wrong. Presuming to know how many words that should be found is the starting point of why this is wrong.

The point of putting the words you found into a list is so that you can separate the responsibility of finding results to printing them.  To decouple them one can't know about the other.  More specifically; you don't care how many are in the list, you just need to know how print the list.  As such you are really just asking "How do I print a list".

Secondly, there is no compiling in python.  Have you tried reading http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ ?
or http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

For code of a correct answer see @enginefree's answer.

Even if you are going to do it the way you are doing it with indexes i would suggest

```
for i in range(0..MAX_ELEMENTS-1):
    print words[i]
```

I also would strongly discourage use of while loops for a problem with a definite knowable boundary of operations such as iteration over a collection from the outset of the operation.  While generally implies changing conditions, unknowable endpoints and the need for custom increment control.